# AppCode editor does not respect multiple target, Swift Compiler Flags

Tags: editor, target, appcode

When I switch to build any target that is not the first target. The code editor does not recognize the target change.

### So any code

```
#if <other target>
...
#endif
```

...is not recognized by appCode editor. When building, works as expected isolating code build for each target.

### Setup: Target Configuration 'Other Swift Flags'

```
-D<other target>
```

In Xcode changing the build target changes what code the editor recognizes. Is there some other place to change this that I can't find? Is this a bug or a limitation?

Comment: What is your #if actually checking? Where does this value come from?

Comment: A flag set on 'Other Swift Flags' under the new target

Comment: And in AppCode, how are you selecting the target?

Comment: Top right menu, Open 'edit / run configurations' select application.

Comment: So that first configuration has your first target. "When I switch to build any target that is not the first target" — are you able to do that, or is that the question?

Comment: All build as expected. The editor does not recognize Other Swift Flags. Looks like it's not supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This functionality is not implemented yet - please, watch [this issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/OC-11349) for further updates.

Comment: Good find. It does look like it has never been supported.